# App event frozen or doesn't refresh when screen is locked + Codename One

Tags: codenameone

iphone screen is locked App screen will show empty or stop the process what App is performing. Do I have to do anything before screen is locked or

Answer (score 0):

When the app is suspended `stop()` is invoked. You should stop networking calls when the app is in suspended state (`isMinimized()`) otherwise the OS might kill your app.

Comment: I have  updated code for stop() method I'm using. Please advise any example to stop networking calls.

Comment: Just don't call `addToQueue()` or `addToQueueAndWait()` after that point.

Comment: I'm calling addToQueueAndWait() for all the network calls. Still form shows as blank when screen lock happens on IOS devices. Thanks

Comment: What do you see in the log native console for the device? Is there an error/exception?

Comment: This happens on the iphone and How would I reproduce this event on simulator? I tried using "Pause App" and not able to reproduce this issue. Please advise.

Comment: You need to get the device log either by connecting it with a cable or using the native logging library https://www.codenameone.com/blog/native-logging-certificate-wizard.html

Comment: I have observed with NativeLogger there is hit on the performance of the App.Is there any known reported issues with NativeLogger ? Most of time it is due logging in the rendering frame information.

Comment: You should use it just to track the issue, I wouldn't use it in production